# Issue in Fetching user's facebook data after user login through my android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

Screenshot of the problem in debug:

[image: Screen shot of the problem]

### Follwoing is my complete code of facebook login file

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.RequestAsyncTask;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    Context context;


    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
               Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                      // callback after Graph API response with user object
                  @Override
                  public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

              if (user != null) {
                        // Display the parsed user info
                      //  userInfoTextView.setText(buildUserInfoDisplay(user));
            //            Log.d(TAG,"Failed to login");
                    }
                  }
                }).executeAsync();

        }

        else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private String buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) {
        StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");

        // Example: typed access (name)
        // - no special permissions required
        userInfo.append(String.format("Name: %s\n\n", user.getName()));

        // Example: typed access (birthday)
        // - requires user_birthday permission
        userInfo.append(String.format("Birthday: %s\n\n", user.getBirthday()));

        // Example: partially typed access, to location field,
        // name key (location)
        // - requires user_location permission
        userInfo.append(String.format("Location: %s\n\n", user.getLocation()
                .getProperty("name")));

        // Example: access via property name (locale)
        // - no special permissions required
        userInfo.append(String.format("Locale: %s\n\n",
                user.getProperty("locale")));

        // Example: access via key for array (languages)
        // - requires user_likes permission
        JSONArray languages = (JSONArray) user.getProperty("languages");
        if (languages.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> languageNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < languages.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject language = languages.optJSONObject(i);
                // Add the language name to a list. Use JSON
                // methods to get access to the name field.
                languageNames.add(language.optString("name"));
            }
            userInfo.append(String.format("Languages: %s\n\n",
                    languageNames.toString()));
        }

        return userInfo.toString();
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_layout, container, false);
        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
                .findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_about_me",
                "user_likes", "user_status", "user_groups"));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Any help regarding this issue will be a great favour thanks...

Comment: You should probably summarize what you are trying to achieve here? Also, you should remove irrelevant parts of your code like all the android Activity life cycle boilerplate code so that its easier to read.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to optimize the code snippets in order to help out experts to track down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code , it might help , working fine in my case.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, final Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };


    private TextView userInfoTextView;
    private String fbAccessToken;
    private ImageView userProfileImg;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);

        authButton.setFragment(this);

        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", "user_birthday", "user_likes"));

        userInfoTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userInfoTextView);

        userProfileImg = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_img);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);

        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
                (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {

            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


        uiHelper.onDestroy();


    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {


        if (state.isOpened()) {

            userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            // Request user data and show the results
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                    if (user != null) {

                        userInfoTextView.setText(buildUserInfoDisplay(user,fbAccessToken));
                    }
                }

            });
        } 

        else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    private String buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user,String token) {



        StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");

        userInfo.append(String.format("Name: %s\n\n",
                user.getName()));


        userInfo.append(String.format("Birthday: %s\n\n",
                user.getBirthday()));


        userInfo.append(String.format("Id: %s\n\n",
                user.getId()));


        userInfo.append(String.format("Locale: %s\n\n",
                user.getProperty("locale")));

        userInfo.append(String.format("Link: %s\n\n",
                user.getLink()));


        userInfo.append(String.format("Gender:%s\n\n",user.asMap().get("gender").toString()));

        userInfo.append(String.format("Token:%s\n\n",token));

        return userInfo.toString();

    }

}
```